# How to use sqlite3 in python on FreeBSD?

Tags: python, sqlite, freebsd

I want to use `sqlite3` in `python` on my `FreeBSD 10.3`. After installing `python`, it prompts I should install the following additional packages:

```
......
===========================================================================

Note that some standard Python modules are provided as separate ports
as they require additional dependencies. They are available as:

bsddb           databases/py-bsddb
gdbm            databases/py-gdbm
sqlite3         databases/py-sqlite3
tkinter         x11-toolkits/py-tkinter

===========================================================================
```

From this [post](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2011-May/230310.html), it seems after installing above `4` packages, the `sqlite3` should be able to work. But "`impore sqlite3`" still reports following errors:

```
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

What other packages should I install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause has been found, I installed **databases/sqlite3**, not **databases/py-sqlite3**. After installing **databases/py-sqlite3**, it works.